# Random variables for parameters in a conservative differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions

I have a system of differential equations in which a variable converts to several other ones. I'd like to add randomness to the parameters, but I am not sure the best approach.

A minimal example (the real one has more terms) is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= -\Gamma \, x,
&
\Gamma &= \sum_{i = 1}^N \gamma_i,
\\
\frac{dy_i}{dt} &= \gamma_i \, x,
&
i &= 1, 2, \ldots, N.
\end{aligned}
$$

I want $\gamma_i$ to be positive constant random variables, preferably similar to normally distributed numbers around a mean/expected value, for example $\Gamma/N$, or uniformly distributed numbers.

One approach I found was sampling from a Dirichlet distribution of size $N$, but I don't know if it is a good approach, or if you can obtain something similar to a normal or uniform distribution using a Dirichlet distribution. I find it difficult to interpret what the $\alpha_i$ mean in this context.

Another naive way was to sample $N$ uniformly distributed numbers in the interval $[0, 1]$ and sort them to obtain a set of random numbers $[\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots, \xi_N]$. Then you can compute differences between the ordered numbers $[\xi_2 - \xi_1, \xi_3 - \xi_2, \ldots, \xi_N - \xi_{N-1}, 1 + \xi_1 - \xi_N]$ (the last term used to make sure the sum of all random numbers sum up to 1). This has a problem tho, because the result is like a half-normal distribution instead.